# Retrieve multiple items of data from database into one single label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to retrieve multiples values from database and display on one label.

My database design currently is:

```
courseid  scholarshipid  course
--------------------------------
    1           1        maths
    2           1        english
    3           1        science

scholarshipid   schName    
-----------------------
      1         moon 
      2         start
      3         light
```

I would like to retrieve this information into one single label such as

```
Maths, English, Science
```

However, now I manage to retrieve one of it which is just maths.

This is my code in code behind:

```
protected void btnShowDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Selectedid = GVFBAcc.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;//get user id
    int selectedIdtoPass = Convert.ToInt32(Selectedid);

    courseBLL getRecord = new courseBLL();
    addcourse courseRetrieve = new addcourse();
    courseRetrieve = getRecord.getCourseDetail(selectedIdtoPass);

    lbCourse.Text = courseRetrieve.course1 + "," + courseRetrieve.course1;
}
```

in my courseBLL

```
public addcourse getCourseDetail(int idcourse)
{
        addcourse userObj = new addcourse();
        courseDAL objtoPass = new courseDAL();
        userObj = objtoPass.displayCourseInfo(idcourse);
        return userObj;
}
```

in my DAL

```
public addcourse displayCourseInfo(int idcourse)
{
        string strCommandText = "Select course from course where schokarshipid = @schokarshipid";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scholarshipid", idcourse);

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        addcourse userObj = new addcourse();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            int sID = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["courseID"].ToString());

            string course = myReader["course"].ToString();

            userObj = new addcourse(sID, course);
        }

        myReader.Close();
        return userObj;
}
```

Edited:

```
public addcourse displayCourseInfo(int idcourse)
{
        var courses = new List<addcourse>();
        string strCommandText = "Select statement here"

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scholarshipid", idcourse);

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            int sID = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["scholarshipid"].ToString());

            string course = myReader["course"].ToString();

            courses.Add(new addcourse(sID,course));
        }

        myReader.Close();

        return courses;
}
```

I have removed some fields for this purpose so that I will not confuse you

Comment: what is happening inside `getCourseDetail()`

Comment: what is ur current output of `lbCourse.Text`??

Comment: i have edited the code please take a look @un-lucky

Comment: current output is: maths, maths

Answer (score 1):

You should return a `List<addcourse>` from `getCourseDetail()` and from `displayCourseInfo` and then you can do this if your `addCourse` has `Course` property:

```
lbCourse.Text = string.Join(", ",  courses.Select(x => x.Course));
```

If the property name is different then change `x.Course` to that.

So in your reader you will do this

```
    var courses = new List<addcourse>();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        int sID = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["courseID"].ToString());

        string course = myReader["course"].ToString();


        courses.Add( new addcourse(sID, course)) ;
   } 
   return courses;
```

Your query is also wrong:

```
Select  course, from course ss inner join  where courseID =@courseID
```

So you should fix that and make sure you get the columns you need because right now it is only getting `course` column and it has syntax errors. Run your query directly against the db using management studio. Once your query works the copy paste it and replace where part with a parameter the way you have it right now.

**EDIT**

It seems you are still stuck with this so I will give you a more detailed answer; however, you should really study up on some fundamental programming concepts. Anyhow, here it is:

Your code behind:

```
protected void btnShowDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Selectedid = GVFBAcc.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;//get user id
    // Make sure this is the scholarshipid or the whole thing will
    // not work.
    int selectedIdtoPass = Convert.ToInt32(Selectedid);

    courseBLL courseRetriever = new courseBLL();

    // Remember you will get a list here
    List<addcourse> courses = courseRetriever.getCourseDetail(selectedIdtoPass);

    // This will take the list and separate the course property with a comma and space
    var courseNames = string.Join(", ", courses);

    // Now assign it to the text property
    lbCourse.Text = courseNames;
}
```

Your BLL:

```
// See here you are retuning a list
// But you need to pass the scholarshipid so you can get the courses for that scholarshipid
public List<addcourse> GerCourses(int scholarshipId)
{
        courseDAL courseRetriever = new courseDAL();

        // Get the list
        List<addcourse> courses = courseRetriever.GetCourses(scholarshipId);
        return courses;
}
```

Your DAL:

```
// See here you are retuning a list
// But you need to pass the scholarshipid so you can get the courses for that scholarshipid
public List<addcourse> GetCourses(int scholarshipId)
{
        // Make sure your query is correct, see you have spelling mistakes
        // it should be scholarshipid not schokarshipid. it has to match the column in your database
        // Make sure your table is called course and it has 3 columns: 1. courseid 2. course
        // 3. scholarshipid or this query will not work
        string strCommandText = "Select courseid, course from course where scholarshipid = @scholarshipId";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scholarshipid", scholarshipId);

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // create a list so we can hold all the courses
        List<addcourse> userObjs = new List<addcourse>();

        // This will read one row at a time so keep reading until there are no more records
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            int sID = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["courseid"].ToString());

            string course = myReader["course"].ToString();

            addcourse userObj = new addcourse(sID, course);

            // add it to the list
            userObjs.Add(userObj);
        }

        myReader.Close();

        // return the list
        return userObjs;
}
```

A few more tips:

1. Give your methods more meaningful names. See the names I gave them `GetCourses`, now it reads like English and it is easy to follow.
2. Your class `addcourse` should be called `Course`. `addcourse` sounds like an action "add course", that could be a good name for a method if you were adding courses. Also use *Pascal* notation for class names and method names. Use *Camel casing* for arguments, parameters and local variables.
3. Learn how to use the Visual Studio debugger. Go watch some YouTube videos on Visual Studio Debugger.

Comment: can you advise me how should i do list<addcourse> ?

Comment: The same way you are calling it now. Just follow my code and return list from those methods

Comment: i got an error saying that it cannot implicitly convert from list to BLL near return courses

Comment: i have added the edit code above, please help to take alook

Comment: my bad. i have some other fields that i want to retrieve and i didnot delete it accordingly. basically courseID is foreign key to another table. hence when courseID = 1, it shld display all those course and other details in another table

Comment: You cannot just copy paste my code. You have to change your method signatures because they are now returning `List<addcourse>`.  Don't just keep trying but think about what you are doing and give it some thought. Programming takes thought and patience. Fix your query syntax errors.

Comment: i have added one new table. basically what i am trying to do is if the scholarshipid = 1 is selected, it should display the scholarshipname and the correspondent  course. eg scholarshipID = 1, output would be, moon, maths,english,science

Comment: hi i need help @codingYoshi

Comment: Hi thank you for ur time to help me. appreciate it alot. i am currently trying to understand and follow the answer u have provided me. However, in my code behind, i have some field that i need to retrieve as well. Should i do this way : var type = (courses);   lbtype.text = type; ? @CodingYoshi

Comment: SrsNyp.App_Code.BLL.addCourse <---- this is what i get when i try to retrieve @CodingYoshi

Comment: there are some typo in ur codes. for bll the name is GerCourses? and in codebehind u called "getCourseDetail" method which i believe it shoild GerCourses instead? @CodingYoshi

Comment: Yes sorry. You will need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a for loop then add it on the variable you are using

Comment: do u have any example?

Comment: i use vb.net, you can convert it if you want

Comment: i have checked your query and it seems that you are calling the courseid which is the id:1 course=maths, try removing the where condition, it will output all the data in your db.